# Can someone clearly explain difference between .Value, .ChildAdded, .ChildChanged, .ChildRemoved for FIRDataEventType?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble putting it into words. Can someone explain what the difference between the different FIRDataEventTypes and examples of when it would be used?

Example (SWIFT):

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user")
queryRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
```

or

```
queryRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
```

From testing, .Value returns one object while .ChildAdded returns multiple; When doing advanced queries .ChildAdded doesn't work but .Value somewhat works (deeper children are null).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[**tl;dr - Watch this video. It uses the old SDK in Android, but the idea is the exact same even for iOS.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FRBDXBs30Y&index=17&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKkg55tSHz0Xc8ZMVS1GJQL)

Each one of these events is a specific way to handle synchronization of data across clients.

The **Value event** will fire each time any piece of data is updated. This could be a newly added key, a deletion of a key, or an update of any value at the reference. **When the change happens the SDK sends back the entire state of the object, not the delta just change that occurred.**

The **Child added event** will fire off once per existing piece of data, the `snapshot` value will be an individual record rather than the entire list like you would get with the **value event**. As more items come in, this event will fire off with each item.

The **Child removed and changed events** work almost the same. When an item is deleted or has it's value changed, the individual item is returned in the callback.

Comment: Damn, that guy in the video is fly. Thanks.

Comment: Does a .childChanged event includes a .childAdded event ? If not, can I pass an array of events with these two to the same observer in Swift ? Thanks

Comment: I second @vbuzze's question: **Is a .childChanged observer notified when children are added?** I seem to be experiencing this. In general it would be great to have a reference to learn these sorts of details of observers. (E.g. what happens when a node whose children you're watching is deleted?) Got a pointer?